# Python fuzzy search and replace

Tags: python, string, nlp, fuzzy-search

I need to perfom fuzzy search for sub-string in string and replace that part. For example:

```
str_a = "Alabama"
str_b = "REPLACED"
orig_str = "Flabama is a state located in the southeastern region of the United States."
print(fuzzy_replace(str_a, str_b, orig_str)) # fuzzy_replace code should be implemented
# Output: REPLACED is a state located in the southeastern region of the United States.
```

The search itself is simple with [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) module, but it gives me only ratio of difference between strings. Are there any ways to find a position in original string where sub-string fuzzy matches to?

Comment: Will that be always single word? If yes we can split by space and replace it if desired ratio passed.

Comment: @itsneo Good idea, but it can contain spaces :(

Comment: Let's fake even more then.... Say we have a string to replace `str_a= "Alabama is a"` which has three words. Now iterate the `orig_str` with `len(str_a)` words. I mean take 3 at a time and iterate it till end which will O(n) complexity. Now replace if ratio passes.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, This crazy answer will be useful for me in future. Let me know how it goes. And kindly comeback and update the answer if you come across any bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def fuzzy_replace(str_a, str_b, orig_str):
    l = len(str_a.split()) # Length to read orig_str chunk by chunk
    splitted = orig_str.split()
    for i in range(len(splitted)-l+1):
        test = " ".join(splitted[i:i+l])
        if fuzz.ratio(str_a, test) > 75: #Using fuzzwuzzy library to test ratio
            before = " ".join(splitted[:i])
            after = " ".join(splitted[i+1:])
            return before+" "+str_b+" "+after #Output will be sandwich of these three strings

str_a = "Alabama is a"
str_b = "REPLACED"
orig_str = "Flabama is a state located in the southeastern region of the United States."
print fuzzy_replace(str_a, str_b, orig_str)
```

This prints

```
 REPLACED state located in the southeastern region of the United States.
```